# I can't access data mapped in beforeRouteEnter in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I want to get the name of the route where the new route comes from, I have the following code, but I cannot access the value assigned in beforeRouteEnter and then use it.

```
 data() {
        return {
            prevRoute: '',
        }
    },
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
        next(vm => {
            vm.prevRoute = from.name
        })
},

mounted() {
console.log(this.prevRoute)
        if (this.prevRoute == "crear-venta") {
            this.imprimirpdf()
        }
},
```

Comment: I solved it with a watch:
watch: {
     prevRoute: 'manipulateData'
   },

Comment: You should be able to use `this.$next` in `mounted`  as well